# Exponential of a 3D multivector in Clifford's Geometric Algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

An arbitrary 3D multivector can be written as the superposition: $M=Z+F$, where $Z=a+bi$ with $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $i$ been the pseudo scalalar of $(Cl_3)$. The remaining term $F=v+iw$, where $v$ and $w$ are vectors of $Cl_3$, have vector and bivector parts, respectively. Since $Z\in$ Cen $(Cl_3)$, the exponential of $M$ becomes
$$\exp(M)=\exp(Z+F)=\exp(Z)\exp(F).$$
To obtain a closed form of $\exp(M)$, I would like to ask if there is a way to show that $$\exp(F)\stackrel{?}{=}\exp(v)\exp(iw)\ldots.$$
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $Cen(Cl_3)$

Comment: Cen$(Cl_{(3,0)})$ consists of those elements which commute with every element of $Cl_{(3,0)}$

Comment: Note that $\operatorname{exp}(A+B)$ only equals to $\operatorname{exp}(A)\operatorname{exp}(B)$ in general if $A$ and $B$ commute (do the Taylor expansion of $\operatorname{exp}(A+B)$ and you will see why; I don't know if there is any special case in which identity holds even if $A$ and $B$ don't commute). Since two $k$-vectors, in Euclidean geometry, of grades $k_1$ and $k_2$, respectively, commute if and only if $k_1 k_2$ is even, $Z$ and $F$ in your case won't commute because $\operatorname{grade}(bi)=3$ and $\operatorname{grade}(v)=1$, so $bi$ and $v$ don't commute.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Peeter Joot, $e^F$ cannot be split into $e^{v}e^{iw}$ since $[v,iw] \neq 0$. So the hunt is on for a decomposition of $F$ into two commuting parts. Fortunatelly, by [staring at Cayley tables](https://bivector.net/tools.html) we can discover that $\mathbb{R}_3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^+_{3,1}$, the even subalgebra of the spacetime algebra, and thus that your $F$ can be viewed as a bivector in spacetime. And for bivectors, we can use the [invariant decomposition](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353116859_Graded_Symmetry_Groups_Plane_and_Simple) to decompose them into commuting terms.

So adapting the invariant decomposition formula slightly using the isomorphism, we can find an $F_1$ and $F_2$ satisfying $F = F_1 + F_2$, $\lambda_i := F_i^2 \in \mathbb{R}$, and $[F_1, F_2] = 0$:

$$F_i = \frac{\lambda_i + \tfrac{1}{2} \langle F^2 \rangle_3}{F},$$

where the $\lambda_i$ are given by

$$\lambda_i = \tfrac{1}{2}  \langle F^2 \rangle_0 \pm \tfrac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \langle F^2 \rangle_0^2 - \langle F^2 \rangle_3^2 }.$$

So we have now found two commuting elements $F_1$ and $F_2$, which both square to scalars so they follow Euler's formula. Specifically, since $\lambda_1 \geq 0$ and $\lambda_2 < 0$, we find

$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{F_1} &= \cosh(\sqrt{\lambda_1}) + \frac{F_1}{\sqrt{\lambda_1}} \sinh(\sqrt{\lambda_1}) \\
e^{F_2} &= \cos(\sqrt{-\lambda_2}) + \frac{F_2}{\sqrt{-\lambda_2}} \sin(\sqrt{-\lambda_2})
\end{aligned}
$$

To conclude, the exponential of any multivector $M = Z + F$ is
$$ e^{M} = e^{a}e^{bi}e^{F_1}e^{F_2}. $$

So the invariant decomposition allows us to bypass the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. For more details and to see how this generalises to higher dimensions I would highly recommend reading the [invariant decomposition](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353116859_Graded_Symmetry_Groups_Plane_and_Simple) paper.

Answer (score 0):

I am note sure whether you can generally find such an exponential factorization.  However, by the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) theorem, we have
$$   e^{A + B + \frac{1}{{2}} \left[{A},{B}\right] + \cdots} = e^A e^B,$$
where $ \left[{A},{B}\right] $, is the commutator, the antisymmetric sum of the objects $ A, B $.
Consider that commutator for your case
$$\begin{aligned}\left[{v},{iw}\right]&=v i w - i w v \\ &=i \left( { v w - w v} \right) \\ &= 2 i \left( { v \wedge w } \right).\end{aligned}$$
Note that this commutator expansion is specific to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ since the pseudoscalar $ i $ happens to commute with all grades in that case.

This expansion shows that if $ v, w $ are colinear, one must have
$$e^{v + iw} = e^v e^{iw}.$$
If $ v, w $ were not colinear, but the higher order commutators happended to be zero, one could say
$$   e^{v + iw + i (v \wedge w)} = e^v e^{iw},$$
but that is not the type of decomposition that you are seeking.